# How add header for swagger generation based on annotation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen, springfox

Consider example:

```
@RequestMapping("myPath")
public Mono<MyDto> myMethod(@RequestParam(value = "amount") Long amount, @AuthenticationPrincipal MyUser user) {

}
```

To skip `MyUser` from parameter list I have added `@AuthenticationPrincipal` to exclusions and springfox generated swagger docs like that:

```
"/myPath": {
  "get": {
    "tags": [
      "my-controller"
    ],
    "summary": "myMethod",
    "operationId": "myMethodUsingGET",
    "produces": [
      "*/*"
    ],
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "amount",
        "in": "query",
        "description": "amount",
        "required": true,
        "type": "integer",
        "format": "int64"
      }
    ],
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "OK",
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Mono«MyDto»"
        }
      },
      "401": {
        "description": "Unauthorized"
      },
      "403": {
        "description": "Forbidden"
      },
      "404": {
        "description": "Not Found"
      }
    },
    "deprecated": false
  }
}
```

Here is spring configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2WebFlux
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        Class[] clazz = {AuthenticationPrincipal.class};

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .ignoredParameterTypes(clazz);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to add a header into swagger documentation generated by [springfox](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/) project for every path where `@AuthenticationPrincipal` specified?
E.g. ignore `MyUser` class as parameter (or parameter group) and replace it with header (like `My-Auth-Header`) for all `@RequestMapping` method where `@AuthenticationPrincipal` is found.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example how to have an `header` parameter called `Auithorization` that i use to add JWT token

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .globalOperationParameters(
                        Collections.singletonList(new ParameterBuilder()
                                .name("Authorization")
                                .description("JWT Authorization token")
                                .modelRef(new ModelRef("string"))
                                .parameterType("header")
                                .required(false)
                                .build()));
    }
}
```

Comment: But this will add `Authorization` token to all API not for methods with `@AuthenticationPrincipal`. :(

Comment: no problem, it's not required, if authentication is not needed you will not populate header